# Netbeans SASS editing: Enter key won't enter when between brackets

Tags: netbeans

Netbeans with the SASS editing plugin.

```
p { font-family: serif; font-size: 15px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
   ^
```

If i put the cursor/caret at the marker above, or even anywhere between the brackets, <kbd>enter</kbd> does nothing.

```
p {
   ^
  font-family: serif; font-size: 15px; margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

In this situation, <kbd>enter</kbd> works. If i condense it to one line, it stops working.

If i delete either bracket, I can do what I want to do then put the bracket back.

I don't know if I accidentally hit something that changed this functionality or not. I seem to remember it working but I can't really be sure. Is this default behaviour? Can it be changed?

Comment: It appears that the magic number for IDE restarts is somewhere around 30. After that many or so restarts, it and reformatting are now working on the one file that was having this.

Comment: Or you can try NetBeans 7.4 (now in Beta) with built-in support for Sass/Less :)